# ValueChangeEvent doesn't get newValue

Tags: jsf, primefaces, ejb

I'm using JSF 2.2.13 and PrimeFaces 6.1.1 in my project. And trying to create primefaces selectOneMenu
which changes locale.But when valueChangeListener is fired - ValueChangeEvent always has null newValue.

ValeuChangeEvent:
[image: ValeuChangeEvent]

**Here is my selectOneMenu:**

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{localeBean.localeCode}" id="lang" valueChangeListener="#{localeBean.valueChangeListener}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="pl" itemLabel="${msg['page.login.language.pl.label']}"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="en" itemLabel="${msg['page.login.language.en.label']}"/>
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="@this"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

**And my LocaleBean:**

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class LocaleBean implements ILocaleBean, Serializable {
    private String           localeCode;
    private Locale           locale;
    private boolean          initiated = false;
    private static final Log log       = LogFactory.getLog(LocaleBean.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        setDefaultLocale();
        this.localeCode = locale.getLanguage();
        initiated = true;

    }

    public void setLocaleCode(String localeCode) {
        this.localeCode = localeCode;
    }

    public String getLocaleCode() {
        if (!initiated) {
            init();
        }
        return getLocale().toString();
    }

    public void valueChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent event) {

        setLocaleFromString(event.getNewValue().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public Locale getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you **try** a recent version of PrimeFaces? Or das it work using normal h:selectOneMenu and f:ajax?

Comment: I tried to switch to normal namespaces but it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you try `<p:ajax` without defining the event? Default is "change" I think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `event="valueChange"` instead of `event="itemSelect"` or leave it empty as suggested by Holger.

Or as the documentation states:

> If no event is specific the default event is called. In addition to
>   the standard events like "change", custom "itemSelect" event is also
>   available to invoke when an item is selected from dropdown.
>
> Default Event: valueChange

When selection happens, the selected value has not yet been submitted, so the listener will not be able to see the new value.

Comment: Finally the problem was solved by moving component inside existing `<h:form> `tag.Thanks for the help!